# Is it possible to query for entities from all fiware-services with Orion-LD?

Tags: fiware-orion

Is it possible to query for entities over all fiware-services?

Example:
I created an entity with type *Example* by an post request with

```
--header 'fiware-service: test' \
--header 'fiware-servicepath: /'
```

Orion-LD creates a schema *orion-test* at the MongoDB where the entity is saved.

Is it possible to query for type *Example* without providing the headers to find all entities with this type not only in the specific service?

Thanks in advance!